# CSS after selector in nav

Tags: css, css-selectors

I try use after selector in my CSS code, but is not well centered.
[image]

I use Bootstrap. When I set after selector on li not a, content moves down.
This is my HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <img src="/images/logo3.png" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="index.ejs">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index.ejs">Prices</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="index.ejs">Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index.ejs">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
</nav>
```

And this is CSS code:

```
.navbar-nav li a::after {
    content: "|" black;
}

.navbar-nav li:last-child a::after {
    content: " ";
}
```

Comment: This seems very overcomplex. You should simply use `display:inline` on your ul's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's working fiddle for you - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ceoet8b6/2/) -

**FYI** : need to expand the result section enough for your menu items to align on a single row.

**PS** : And I'm just hoping that you use ***my suggestion number 2*** there ( the best would the third, but it depends on what kind of menu you need ). Using pseudo class to get those separators in your menu isn't a good practice. It could save the amount of HTML codes, but that's more like it when you use additional `li` between those menu items.

---

**EXPLANATION**

Your CSS was almost there, but you made a mistake.

```
content: "|" black;
```

You can't use `CSS shorthand` on the `content` attribute. And you need to give the `::after` pseudo class `padding-left` to make it center-aligned.

Try above [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ceoet8b6/2/) Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

This is a comment, but I think it's the right answer so ^^

This seems very overcomplex. You should simply use display:inline on your ul's and then use padding for spacing between the list items. You can then float left and right the two individual lists respectively to get the positioning :).